# Vagrant Multimachine: How connect to MySQL database from another vagrant machine

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Vagrantfile

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"

 config.vm.define "web" do |web|
   web.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-14.04"
   web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
   web.vm.hostname = "database"
 end

 config.vm.define "db" do |db|
   db.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
   db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
 end
end
```

Installed mysql-server 8 on db box and mysql-client on web box. When connecting to mysql from web to db by  `mysql -u root -p -h database` and then get error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database' (111)`

Answer (score 1):

By default mysql listens only on the localhost. Make sure you change the configuration and bind to 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.33.11.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address